# Docker Push Broken with Nginx Proxy on Private Registry

Tags: nginx, docker

I setup a private docker registry using the [standard registry image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/registry/) and an [nginx proxy](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) for SSL and basic auth. When I push a docker image to the private registry, the image is uploaded, but tags are not updated. This includes the latest tags. If I hit https://example.com/v1/repositories/library/example/tags in my browser, the response is an empty object {}.

If I remove nginx and push directly to the registry, everything works fine. I can't figure out what about the nginx proxy is messing up the tags update. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to [marvambass/nginx-registry-proxy](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/marvambass/nginx-registry-proxy/) for providing security and this resolved the problem.

Comment: please mark it as accepted if this solved the issue